# Extracting convex_hull polygon from CSVwith scipy.spatial ConvexHull and output it to a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, csv, convex-hull, scipy.spatial

I'm looking for a Python solution for extract a convex_hull polygon from quite big CSV (nearly 150 millions points) and return back the polygon to a shapefile.
After reading the CSV with pandas (`pd.read_csv`), I give a change to  `scipy.spatial` `Convex_Hull` due to very quick response time. And effectively I get the convex_hull envelope correctly estimates.

But I'm now in the hurdles, because I've not a solution to  export the result (a `scipy.spatial.qhull.ConvexHull` ). If I understand correctly, I need to extract from the hull structure the points or vertices, because no polygon is available.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With geopandas and shapely you can do:

```py
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull as ch
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd
xfield, yfield = 'xcoord', 'ycoord'
epsg = 3006
csvfile = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\many_points.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile) 
arr = df[[xfield, yfield]].to_numpy() #Create numpy array from coordinates
hull = ch(arr) #Calculate convex hull

polylist = []
for idx in hull.vertices: #Indices of points forming the vertices of the convex hull.
    polylist.append(arr[idx]) #Append this index point to list
#polylist[:2]
#Out[61]: [array([ 757300.23175, 6432516.2335 ]), array([ 919182.325 , 7307516.6095])]

p = Polygon(polylist)
df = pd.DataFrame({'hull':[1]})
df['geometry'] = p
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs='EPSG:{}'.format(epsg), geometry='geometry')
gdf.to_file( r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\many_points_convex_hull.shp")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!